# How to send and receive HTTP requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to send HTTP requests from client side javascript and display all the response neatly in HTML(headers, content, additional text etc).

In addition to this I also want to code javascript that sends a particular response when someone visits the web page. For example, if I want to send the 402(payment required) when someone visits example.com/test, how do I do it in client side javascript?

Comment: Google AJAX - you will get many answers

Comment: You can't set response codes in client-side JavaScript.  You'll need to run something on a server somewhere.

Comment: What if I use MeteorJS?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple javascript snippet to make a request and print the responses,

```
function createHttpObject() {
     try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
     catch (error) {}
     try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
     catch (error) {}
     try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
     catch (error) {}

     throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}

var request = new createHttpObject();
request.open("GET", "url", true);
request.send(null);
print(request.responseText);
```

Edit:added an incompatibility wrapper for old versions of internet explorer.

The XMLHttpRequest object provides for allowing you to make web requests.

Here,in open the first argument specifies which HTTP method to use to process your request. The values you can specify are GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE.
In this case, we are interested in receiving information, so the first argument we specify is going to be GET.The last argument is to specify if the request is asynchronous or not,true specifies it is asynchronous.

The send function sends the request and the argument specifies data to be sent with the request.For get it is left null.

Comment: Why not suggest the use of jQuery? You know that Internet Explorer breaks with this kind of code?

Comment: Here I added a quick incompatibility wrapper for those older browsers.And yes jQuery is obviously an efficient option, but this is also a way.

Comment: @chx101 Internet Explorer has natively supported XMLHttpRequest since 7.0 was released in 2006. The ActiveXObject workaround is only required for IE6 or earlier, which are thoroughly obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to send a HTTP request and receive its response.

I like to use Jquery Ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

It is simple and a lot of help can be found

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using Jquery in order to make an HTTP get request :

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/api/...', //here is your URL
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
       //the data here is the response data 

    },
    error: function(e) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to send HTTP requests from client side javascript and
>   display all the response neatly in HTML(headers, content, additional
>   text etc).

For this task use [jQuery.post()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)

> In addition to this I also want to code javascript that sends a
>   particular response when someone visits the web page. For example, if
>   I want to send the 402(payment required) when someone visits
>   example.com/test, how do I do it in client side javascript?

JavaScript runs on the client side only. If you want to use JavaScript on server I suggest you use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). But there's no need to use JS on the server side because there are plenty of server scripting and programming languages. You can use [Java EE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/), [PHP](https://secure.php.net/), [Perl](http://www.tizag.com/perlT/), and [Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/) to achieve what you are looking for.

Now, as for your logic, you must first have a secure session in place about the user. If there isn't one they must sign in. This is where you'll need a database. I also strongly recommend you use [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) when interacting with your database.

Comment: @Satonamo https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods , https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/adding-user-accounts. But I strongly recommend the use of technologies made specifically for server side processing. If you are planning on hosting meteor.js on your own then by all means do so, otherwise there aren't many web hosting companies that support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

https://github.com/floscodes/JS/blob/master/Requests.js

You can easily send a http-Request. Just use:

```
HttpRequest("https://example.com", method="post", data="yourkey=yourdata");
```

That's it! It should even work if the site is CSRF-protected.

Or just send a GET-Request by using

```
HttpRequest("https://example.com", method="get");
```